# $s$-wave scattering approximation of the two-body interaction

Tags: scattering, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

In quantum gases, one usually approximates the two-body interaction $V(\boldsymbol{r})$ with a s-wave delta potential $$V_{\text{pseudo}}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \frac{4\pi \hbar^2 a}{m} \delta (\boldsymbol{r})$$ for low-energy processes, where $a$ is the scattering length of $V(r)$. I understand that the factor in $V_{\text{pseudo}}$ is to produce the same phase shift (or the scattering length $a$) as that of $V$, but why is this a good approximation of the original $V(r)$?

As illustrated in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191093/), we can still have an attractive potential $V(\boldsymbol{r})$ even if the scattering length $a>0$.
Then does it make sense to approximate this attractive potential with a repulsive one $V_{\text{pseudo}}$?